# Loop for file search in Windows batch file

Tags: windows, file, search, loops, batch-file

I need a script to search a file say abc.txt in a folder say XYZ until it finds it is generated in that location. The script should search the file after every 60 sec. Once the file is generated it should perform a certain task, say copying it to some location.

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are two alternatives.

1. Either schedule a batch in the task scheduler. This is the alternative I recommend.

   - first, create your checkabc.bat file, similar to this

     ```
     @echo off
     if exist c:\xyz\abc.txt (
       rem do here what you want
     )
     ```
   - and then, schedule to run every minute

     ```
     schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 1 /tn "check abc.txt exists" /tr "cmd /c c:\bats\checkabc.bat"
     ```
2. Or...  loop in your batch file

   ```
   :DOCHECK
   IF EXIST abc.txt (
     ECHO abc.txt exists, do your things here...
   )
   WAIT60SECS
   GOTO :DOCHECK
   ```

   but, oops, WAIT60SECS is a command that does not exist. There are different ways to implement it. See http://www.robvanderwoude.com/wait.php

Answer (score 0):

I think here you are looking for file watcher. If you want to use Java, following link will be useful to you:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

You can get file-name from event by following way:

```
  WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>)event;
  Path filename = ev.context();
```

And then you can do the task you want to do, if file get created.